# Positioning a background image in an element with an offset from the bottom

Tags: html, css, background-image

Is there a way to set a background to be fixed to the center, and to the bottom, but not flush with the bottom of the element, rather 100px up from the bottom of the element?

[image: the illustration of the issue at hand]

(Of course the bg image would only be visible with in the div bounds)

This is what i have so far, but don't know how to bump the image up 100px from the bottom.

```
background: url("/path/to/bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed center bottom #FFF;
```

(no javascript answers please)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple:

```
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url("/path/to/bg.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center bottom 100px; /* answer */
```

**Ref:** http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position

*More to read:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: Thanks this will work. One more thing to match exactly what I was going for: `background-attachment:fixed;` :)